# What's an example of a square matrix $A$ that has a larger column space than $A^2$, i.e. $C(A) > C(A^2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If in $\mathbf{R}^2$, I thought a transformation matrix that corresponds to the rotation of only one axis (X or Y) by 45 degrees would satisfy as an example, is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a nilpotent matrix, like $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$?

Comment: Nice, that works. Does a matrix that only rotates one axis exist?

Comment: The matrix $\pmatrix{\frac1{\sqrt2}&&0\\\frac1{\sqrt2}&&1}$ rotates the $x$- but not the $y$-axis, but is not an example of what you're looking for